# Add Backgrid.Filter for each column

Tags: backbone.js, backgrid

I have to add filter for each column like this:
[image: Filter for each column in Backgrid]

But I can't understand how should I extend [Backgrid.Header](http://backgridjs.com/#api-header) to achieve this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this ticket on the [official repository](https://github.com/wyuenho/backgrid/issues/409).